# How to print text many time in Java? (use self-written methods and while-structure)

Tags: java

I'm doing this really basic Java Programming course.
The aim of the exercise is to ask the user how many times the text has to be printed, and then print it. But as in the comment in the code it was said that ''do  not change method definition'' , I have no idea how to proceed to print the text the amount asked. (I was thinking that the i could be added somehow to the method but idk)

Here is the code what I have done so far:

```
public class ManyPrints {

// NOTE: do not change the method definition, e.g. add parameters to method
public static void printText() {
    System.out.println("In the beginning there were the swamp, the hoe and     Java.");
    // Write your code here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ask the user how many times the text should be printed
    // use the while structure to call the printText method several times
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many?");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= number) {
    i++;
    printText();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance if you have the time to help me !:)

Comment: The while loop should do the job, even if a for loop would be better :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here

Comment: @TobiasR. why would a for loop be better? There's no performance difference, and the condition is the exact same. It's just 2 different ways of writing the same loop.

Comment: Doesn't this code work as it shuold?

Comment: @Sterling Archer in my opinion the for loop would be just a better style in this case. no performace reason.

Comment: It looks like the comment actually meant to say "do not change the method **declaration**" instead of "definition". In other words: don't add parameters, change the return type or name of the method, but do change the content of the method.

Comment: @TobiasR. note that it seems a `while` loop is a required aspect of the assignment ;) However, it's irrelevant because I haven't used a while loop in many years lol

Comment: by starting `i` at 0 and doing `<=` in the while loop it will print it `number + 1` times, which I don't think is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code except a few points, **you did great.**

- you need to `import Scanner`
- change `i = 0;`to`i = 1;`

So you get this

```
import java.util.Scanner;//Add this line

public class ManyPrints {

    public static void printText() {//no problems here
        System.out.println("In the beginning there were the swamp, the hoe and     Java.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many?");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int i = 1;//it should be i = 1; and not i = 0;
        while (i <= number) {
            i++;
            printText();
        }
    }//done
}
```

Now if you want to proceed further(I take it that you are a complete beginner).
Get a simple IDE like BlueJ. Create a class. Write the code. Compile it. Run it.

You get the output.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

As i see your given code, you take a variable int i = 0; and make a condition i <= number in a while loop. Which is counting from 0 to given number. Suppose given number is 10. So the loop is counting 0 to 10 and the text is printing 11 time.And you also need a Scanner class.So your code should look like,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ManyPrints {

// NOTE: do not change the method definition, e.g. add parameters to method
public static void printText() {
    System.out.println("In the beginning there were the swamp, the hoe and     Java.");
    // Write your code here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ask the user how many times the text should be printed
    // use the while structure to call the printText method several times
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many?");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= number) {
    i++;
    printText();
    }
}
}
```